# Specify a file path that begins with the top-most directory

Tags: java, string, file

I'm printing the following line:

`Files.exists(Paths.get("card/1.png"),java.nio.file.LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);`

Using `Paths.get(...)`, I want to retrieve the path of a folder *beginning* at my root directory, however, and not at my current working directory. I vaguely remember, but now cannot recall, some expression that begins file retrieval at the root.

The expression was similar to `~/` so that I could write `Paths.get(~/A/B);`

If no such expression exists, what's the best alternative to beginning a retrieval at a user's top most folder?

Comment: What's the name of the root directory? How do you go there from your terminal?

Comment: `/Users/rohitkumar`. I use `cd ~/`

Comment: So, that's not the root directory. The root directory is `/`. What you want is your *home* directory. `System.getProperty("user.home")`

Comment: Yes, you have me. I wanted my home directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find your home dir first and then use "resolve" with a relative path:

```
Path homeDir = Path.get(System.getProperty("user.home"));
Path filePath = homeDir.resolve("card/1.png");
```

Here is the [JavaDoc of the resolve function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve(java.nio.file.Path)). The relativize function might also be useful in this context.